# Why doesn't IDLE show class data attributes?

Tags: python, python-idle, python-3.4

I have a Python class module open in an IDLE (3.4.1) editor window. The class consists of data attributes and methods. When opening the Class Browser (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), I see the list of methods, but not the data attributes. Why is that?

```
class Test:

    a = 1
    b = 2

    def meth1(self):
        print(self.a)

    def meth2(self):
        print(self.b)
```

[image]

Comment: Short answer: IDLE is crappy. Use any other editor of your liking.

Comment: @Davidmh - I only started learning Python 2 days ago. I did notice that for a package that's supposedly a couple of years old, the level of immaturity is surprising. Many features that are considered standard in any half decent modern editor/IDE are missing here. I can understand the minimalism philosophy, but some features are really good additions to any programming editor.

Comment: It is actually 15 years old! It is supposed to avoid feature clutter and be cross platform; while keeping the size to a minimum, as it is bundled with CPython.

Answer (score 0):

It don't support it. Thats all. It's true that is 15 years old (as mentioned by **Davidmh**) and *It is supposed to avoid feature clutter...* but that not justify the lack of such functionality.